# Using JSON how to assign multiple images or a better way of doing it suggested?

Tags: javascript, json

At the moment I'm using JSON to call words for my games I'm making but I wondering if I could do it with multiple images without a massive length of code for each round. Here is what I got so far but it's complaining about the duplicate "url". Or would I be better of using an array

Thanks

```
{
"images": [
    {"imageID" : "game1", "url" : "gameImages/img1.jpg", "url" : "gameImages/img2.jpg",
  "url" : "gameImages/img3.jpg", "url" : "gameImages/img4.jpg"  }

    {"imageID" : "game2", "url" : "gameImages/img5.jpg", "url" : "gameImages/img6.jpg",
  "url" : "gameImages/img7.jpg", "url" : "gameImages/img8.jpg"  }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can use one image as sprite, 0-1000px = first image, 1001px - 2000px = second image, and so on.. this way you wont be needing the JSON at all + only 1 image

Comment: Ah yes forgot about sprites, I'll end up using it after I get it the functionality going in the game so thank you Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appears you're aware of the use of arrays in JSON already (you have two entries within your `images` array already), how about storing each set of urls in an array:

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "imageID": "game1",
            "urls": [
                "gameImages/img1.jpg",
                "gameImages/img2.jpg",
                "gameImages/img3.jpg",
                "gameImages/img4.jpg"
            ]
        },
        {
            "imageID": "game2",
            "urls": [
                "gameImages/img5.jpg",
                "gameImages/img6.jpg",
                "gameImages/img7.jpg",
                "gameImages/img8.jpg"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```